# How to set up a https foward proxy for curl

Tags: curl, https, proxy

I am facing one problem, and not get solution on google

I try to use curl to visit a https website behind a proxy but fail.

It is success without proxy or visit without ssl. Then I deployed a tcp proxy (got from https://github.com/kklis/proxy), and set enviroment `export https_proxy=127.0.0.1:443`

visit https://www.baidu.com, I just got `connection aborted` error

Here is how I run proxy:

`./proxy -l 8111 -h www.baidu.com -p 443`

And set proxy environment:

`export https_proxy=127.0.0.1:8111`

Run curl:

`curl -v https://www.baidu.com`

Got result:

> Rebuilt URL to: https://www.baidu.com/
>
> Trying 127.0.0.1...
>
> Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 8111 (#0)
>
> Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to www.baidu.com:443
>
> CONNECT www.baidu.com:443 HTTP/1.1
>
> Host: www.baidu.com:443
>
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
>
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
>
> Proxy CONNECT aborted
>
> Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
>
> curl: (56) Proxy CONNECT aborted

I tried add --insecure and not work, same result.

I think this is the same issue some one has met, still no answer:
https://github.com/h2non/balboa/issues/1

Thanks if anyone can help!

Answer (score 0):

I think I know the reason

I captured packets , using proxy to visit a https website , curl will start a HTTP CONNECT method to establish a tunnel. The tunnel should be between curl client and proxy, but TCP proxy will delivery all messages to web server, so web server will reset the connection.

A forward proxy should not just delivery messages between client and web server.It should understand the HTTP CONNECT method

I use a standard foward proxy - squid instead, then success.

Hope this helps