# HAProxy settings for connecting to Snowflake Data

Tags: haproxy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've been trying to connect to Snowflake using the ODBC driver via a proxy but have so far been unable to. I'm using HAProxy to do this.

This is from `odbc.ini`, where I've configured my DSN:

```
[ODBC Data Sources]
SnowflakeDSII = Snowflake

[SnowflakeDSII]
Server = <account>.<region>.snowflakecomputing.com
Port = 443
UID = <username>
PWD = <password>
Schema =
Warehouse =
Driver = /opt/snowflake/snowflakeodbc/lib/universal/libSnowflake.dylib
Description = Snowflake DSII
Locale = en-US
Tracing = 0
proxy = http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

This is my HAProxy config:

```
global
  log stdout format raw local0 info

defaults
  log global
  # timeouts
  timeout connect 3600s
  timeout client 3600s
  timeout server 3600s
  maxconn 4000

frontend snowflake_proxy
  mode tcp
  option tcplog

  bind 0.0.0.0:8000
  default_backend snowflake

backend snowflake
  mode tcp
  option tcp-check
  server server0 <account>.<region>.snowflakecomputing.com:443 check
```

On running `iodbctest`, I'm seeing this error:

```
OOB curl_easy_perform() failed: Failure when receiving data from the peer
1: SQLDriverConnect = [Snowflake][Snowflake] (4)
      REST request for URL https://<account>.<region>.snowflakecomputing.com:443/session/v1/login-request?requestId=0fe536ed-4d6c-4858-b468-52a6757248a7&request_guid=5477913c-989a-4da3-bbbc-b62a68391749 failed: CURLerror (curl_easy_perform() failed) - code=56 msg='Failure when receiving data from the peer' osCode=36 osMsg='Operation now in progress'.
     (4) SQLSTATE=HY000
1: ODBC_Connect = [Snowflake][Snowflake] (4)
      REST request for URL https://<account>.<region>.snowflakecomputing.com:443/session/v1/login-request?requestId=0fe536ed-4d6c-4858-b468-52a6757248a7&request_guid=5477913c-989a-4da3-bbbc-b62a68391749 failed: CURLerror (curl_easy_perform() failed) - code=56 msg='Failure when receiving data from the peer' osCode=36 osMsg='Operation now in progress'.
     (4) SQLSTATE=HY000
```

---

I've also tried configuring HAProxy to act as just a simple HTTP proxy. This is my HAProxy configuration for that:

```
global
  log stdout format raw local0 info

defaults
  log global
  # timeouts
  timeout connect 3600s
  timeout client 3600s
  timeout server 3600s
  maxconn 4000

frontend snowflake_proxy
  mode http
  option httplog

  bind 0.0.0.0:8000
  default_backend snowflake

backend snowflake
  mode http
  option http-server-close
  option http_proxy
```

With the above HAProxy config, I'm seeing this error:

```
OOB curl_easy_perform() failed: Failure when receiving data from the peer
1: SQLDriverConnect = [Snowflake][Snowflake] (4)
      REST request for URL https://<account>.<region>.snowflakecomputing.com:443/session/v1/login-request?requestId=01ccf8d9-895b-47d1-9102-41f7524ec436&request_guid=773e75b3-9137-4862-a5e1-3bf49e076a1d failed: CURLerror (curl_easy_perform() failed) - code=56 msg='Failure when receiving data from the peer'.
     (4) SQLSTATE=HY000
1: ODBC_Connect = [Snowflake][Snowflake] (4)
      REST request for URL https://<account>.<region>.snowflakecomputing.com:443/session/v1/login-request?requestId=01ccf8d9-895b-47d1-9102-41f7524ec436&request_guid=773e75b3-9137-4862-a5e1-3bf49e076a1d failed: CURLerror (curl_easy_perform() failed) - code=56 msg='Failure when receiving data from the peer'.
     (4) SQLSTATE=HY000
```

From HAProxy's logs:

```
127.0.0.1:64824 [31/Jan/2020:13:28:19.888] snowflake_proxy snowflake/<NOSRV> -1/-1/-1/-1/0 400 211 - - PR-- 1/1/0/0/3 0/0 "CONNECT <account>.<region>.snowflakecomputing.com:443 HTTP/1.1"
127.0.0.1:64825 [31/Jan/2020:13:28:21.890] snowflake_proxy snowflake/<NOSRV> -1/-1/-1/-1/0 400 211 - - PR-- 1/1/0/0/3 0/0 "CONNECT <account>.<region>.snowflakecomputing.com:443 HTTP/1.1"
127.0.0.1:64826 [31/Jan/2020:13:28:25.894] snowflake_proxy snowflake/<NOSRV> -1/-1/-1/-1/0 400 211 - - PR-- 1/1/0/0/3 0/0 "CONNECT <account>.<region>.snowflakecomputing.com:443 HTTP/1.1"
127.0.0.1:64829 [31/Jan/2020:13:28:33.898] snowflake_proxy snowflake/<NOSRV> -1/-1/-1/-1/0 400 211 - - PR-- 1/1/0/0/3 0/0 "CONNECT <account>.<region>.snowflakecomputing.com:443 HTTP/1.1"
127.0.0.1:64830 [31/Jan/2020:13:28:33.903] snowflake_proxy snowflake/<NOSRV> -1/-1/-1/-1/0 400 211 - - PR-- 1/1/0/0/3 0/0 "CONNECT sfctest.client-telemetry.snowflakecomputing.com:443 HTTP/1.1"
```

Has anyone had any luck doing something similar? Would you be able to share relevant parts of your HAProxy config please?

Comment: Does this "Proxy" configuration affect your connection settings?  https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/ODBC-Driver-Proxy-Server-Parameters-Obsolete noted in the documentations: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/odbc-parameters.html#using-configuration-parameters Are they environmental variables? https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/odbc-parameters.html#connecting-through-a-proxy-server

Comment: The environment variables mess up my application for some reason -- one of the libraries uses the same environment variable. I doubt it's the Proxy configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the requirement for SSL pass-through to be configured on the proxy, HAProxy might be difficult if not impossible to configure and use as a forwarding proxy for Snowflake's ODBC driver.

The reason is stated in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53493932/how-to-set-up-a-https-foward-proxy-for-curl):

> I captured packets , using proxy to visit a https website , curl will start a HTTP CONNECT method to establish a tunnel. The tunnel should be between curl client and proxy, but TCP proxy will delivery all messages to web server, so web server will reset the connection.
>
> A forward proxy should not just delivery messages between client and web server.It should understand the HTTP CONNECT method

HAProxy when doing SSL pass-through behaves as a TCP proxy, and so does not parse the underlying messages. However it needs to first set up the tunnel before doing so and that requires responding to the HTTP `CONNECT` method.